# Why shared_ptr type has no template allocator parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, allocator

shared_ptr is defined as

```
template< class T > class shared_ptr;
```

the custom allocator is passed as constructor argument

```
template< class Y, class Deleter, class Alloc >
shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d, Alloc alloc );
```

Why there is no

```
template< class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> > class shared_ptr;
```

?

I have the feeling that this make life easier in certain cases, but on the other end it prevents doing something like:

```
namespace App{
    template <typename T>
    using Shared = std::shared_ptr<T,myAllocator<T>>; //pool allocator for control blocks
}
```

Also make_shared does not allows that because it already takes as arguments the constructor's arguments.

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't make life easier as it would artifically constrict any client of `shared_ptr` to either be tied to one particular allocator type or itself by templated on an allocator type.

Only some constructors and functions (e.g. some `reset` overloads) need to know about the allocator used to allocated the shared object. Many clients can happily be allocator agnostic.

Having fewer template parameters on the type is *less* constraining. Note that template parameters on class types must usually be specified explicitly where as on function templates they can often be deduced from parameters.